# SMTP library Python3 : Less secure app access

Tags: python-3.x, smtp

As of May 30th Google has removed allowing less secure app access for G-Mail. I am using SMTP library to send emails from my flask website and as this method requires the feature that Google has just removed, I am stuck. I am looking for any work-arounds or alternate solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple and does not require much change:

1. [Turn on 2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839) in your google account. This step is **required** as Google only allows generating passwords for apps on accounts that have 2-Step Verification enabled.
2. Go to generate apps password (https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) and [generate a password](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en-GB) for your app.

[image]

3. Simply use your gmail username (`your_mail@gmail.com`) and the password generated in your python application.

I have tested what I just attached to you with the following script:

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
mail_content = '''
Hello Stack Overflow!!!
'''

sender_address = 'your_mail@gmail.com'
sender_pass = 'generated_password'
receiver_address = 'your_mail@gmail.com'

message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'A test mail sent by Python.'   

message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
session.starttls()
session.login(sender_address, sender_pass)
text = message.as_string()
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
session.quit()
print('Mail Sent')
```

And it worked without problems:
[image]