# is there an alternative way of turning on less secure app from gmail?

Tags: php, xampp, gmail

Hello guys I'm using xampp in sending mail using mail() but I think i need to turn off the less secure app but since google removed it anyone know any alternative to make the code run.

```
<?php
            $receiver = "2020@gmail.com";
            $subject = "Email Verification Code";
            $message = "Your verification code is ";
            $sender = "From: NatsuDragneelxd42069@gmail.com";
            if(mail($receiver, $subject, $message, $sender))
            {
                echo "Email sent successfully to $receiver";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Sorry, failed while sending mail!";
            }
```

?>

modified php.ini and sendmail.ini

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"

[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

please comment if you know alternative to the less secure app or if you spot error in the code.

Comment: The solution to your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72553362

Answer (score 4):

No.

Google removed support for less secure apps.

They didn't remove one way of enabling it while leaving a backdoor that would make the deprecation pointless.

If you want to use GMail as your email backend, use [their API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending). If you want to continue using SMTP then you'll need to find a different email service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. do you have any suggestions on how I should approach email OTP in xampp(localhost)?

Answer (score 0):

Google Workspace has been migrating to Oauth 2.0 protocol almost all of their service, even gmail soon wont accepts protocols like IMAP to check mails an  smtp will be accepted, but seems like SMTP is goint to be deprecated some day soon

> Google and Microsoft announced basic authentication deprecation for
> their email services in 2022. Both companies consider Basic
> authentication as an outdated industry standard and thus they are
> suggesting its customer moving to OAuth 2.0 token-based authorization.

source:[Article Deprecation Basic Auth](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Knowledge/Deprecation-of-basic-authentication-for-Exchange-Online-and/ta-p/1929311)

maybe could help you this Tutorial [Tutorial use of Oauth to send](https://www.labnol.org/google-api-service-account-220405)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is way via enabling apppasswords.
Note: 2-factor authentication needs to be enabled if not enabled already.

Less secure apps (https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps) options is disabled.

Instead use apppasswords using following link.
https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/apppasswords

Use 16 digit code provided by google instead of password and that should be it.

[image]