# Unable to send emails through Flask-mail

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-mail

I have been trying to create a web app which takes email address as an input through HTML form and sends a one time pin for further access to website.

1. I have 2 html files in my template folder (one for taking user's email address and other for OTP entering)
2. i have `config.json` file which stores my accountid and password through which i intend to send the OTP.

.py file

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from random import randint
import json
from flask_mail import *

with open('config.json','r') as f:
    params = json.load(f)['params']
mail = Mail(app)

otp = randint(100,999)      #otp production

app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = params['gmail-user']
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = params['gmail-password']


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return(render_template('otpgive.html'))

@app.route('/getOTP', methods = ['POST'])
def getOTP(): #OTP send and Verify here
    email_id = request.form['usermail']
    msg = Message('OTP for the APPLICATION', sender = 'my_email', recipients = [email_id]) 

  #my_email is the email through which i plan to send messages.

    msg.body = "Greetings! Your email has been verified successfully. Kindly note your OTP is " + str(otp)
    mail.send(msg)
    return render_template('otpconfirm.html')

@app.route('/validateOTP', methods = ['POST'])
def validateOTP():
    userotp = request.form['otp']
    if (otp == int(userotp)):
        return ("Email Verified Succcessfully ")
    else:
        return render_template('otpgive.html',msg = 'incorrect otp')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = False)
    #app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000, debug = True)
```

Solutions I tried but failed:

1. Tried disabling the firewall.
2. Tried setting the port number for 0.0.0.0
3. Tried `debug = False`

I was expecting it to work. i.e send emails to the users but it shows ConnectionError or InternalServerError

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

> ConnectionRefusedError:
>
> [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the solution.

1. Since I was using G-Mail, I had to enable 2FA (2-Factor Auth) first on my profile, and then generate a new password for my app.
2. The password thus obtained was pasted in the `config.json` file instead of my
   main profile password.

Used directions from this thread [Less Secure option in gmail unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547853/unable-to-send-email-in-c-sharp-less-secure-app-access-not-longer-available/72553362#72553362)

---

Now Changes I made in my code:

1. Reverted back to ip: `host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug = True`
2. I kept firewall disabled as a precaution.

I repositioned `mail = Mail(app)` line to after all `app.config`s